# Detecting Pan Gesture End

Tags: objective-c, touch, uigesturerecognizer

I've got a view and I applied a UIPanGestureRecogniser to this view:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panAnim:)];
[sliderView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
[panGesture release];
```

I can detect and process the gesture just fine. However, I wish to initiate another method once the gesture has ended.

I know there are two methods that allow this kind of detection. `touchesEnded` and `touchesCancelled` however, I've found that `touchesCancelled` gets called as soon as the touch becomes a gesture i.e. I move my finger enough to warrant a gesture call and `touchesEnded` rarely, if ever, gets called.

I want to be able to pan left / right and then initiate another function call upon gesture ending. How do I do this?

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Pan gesture end event can be detected by checking its state with `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`.

Check with the below code .

```
-(void) panAnim:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*) gestureRecognizer
{
   if(gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
   {
      //All fingers are lifted.
   }
}
```

From Apple documentation

> A panning gesture is continuous. It
> begins (UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
> when the minimum number of fingers
> allowed (minimumNumberOfTouches) has
> moved enough to be considered a pan.
> It changes
> (UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) when
> a finger moves while at least the
> minimum number of fingers are pressed
> down. It ends
> (UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) when
> all fingers are lifted.

[Read more about UIPanGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipangesturerecognizer)

Comment: @Daniel Hanly: glad to know it help u :)

Comment: For swift 5+ it should be `gestureRecognizer.state == .ended` or `gestureRecognizer.state == UIPanGestureRecognizer.State.ended`

Answer (score 11):

Pan gesture end event can be detected by checking the it's state with `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` or `UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled` or `UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed`

Check with the below code .

```
   -(void) panGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*) gestureRecognizer
    {
     if(gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded || gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed || gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled)
             {
                //code what you want.
             }
     }
```

Answer (score 9):

Above answers are all correct, this is just an updated one for Swift.

**Swift 3:**

```
func panGesture(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if recognizer.state == .ended {
        // Do what you want
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 4, use UIGestureRecognizerState.ended.

e.g.

```
if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended) {

        //Move label back to original position (function invoked when gesture stops)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
            self.swipeLabel.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.width / 2, y: self.view.bounds.height / 2)
        }
    }
```

Below is all the code you need in a view controller to animate a UILabel with gesture, including when the gesture ends.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var swipeLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Create gesture
    let gestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(moveLabelBasedOn(gestureRecognizer:)))

    //Assign gesture to UILabel
    swipeLabel.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)

}

//Animate Label in Resopnse to Gesture
@objc func moveLabelBasedOn(gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let changeInPosition = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: view)

    //Move label in response to gesture
    swipeLabel.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.width / 2 + changeInPosition.x, y: view.bounds.height / 2 + changeInPosition.y)

    //Check if gesture ended
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended) {

        //Move label back to original position (function invoked when gesture stops)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
            self.swipeLabel.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.width / 2, y: self.view.bounds.height / 2)
        }
    }
}

}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This would not work for a two (or more) finger pan. In this case with `numberOfMinimumTouches = 2`, the pan would start and you can scroll/pan around, but if you lift one finger, the pan will still continue (move to where the one finger is instead of between the two fingers), since the `State.ended` is only when **ALL** fingers are lifted. To stop based on the `numberOfMinimumTouches` value, a different approach needs to be implemented.